# SSIS C# script task File.Exist not working

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a script task in C# running in SSIS that is checking if the file exists in a network shared drive. Here is the line of the code:

```
string f = @"\\files1\Public\Automated Reports\VENDOR_STORE_ITEM_2015-05-04.xlsx";


        if (File.Exists(f))....
```

even though the file exists, it says it does not!!! please help.

I was wondering if has anything to do with anonymous authentication being disabled or so...

Comment: actually, the network shared drive is on a server.

Comment: What user is running the script? Does that user have access to the share? do you have an exception?

Comment: Note that `File.Exists` will return `false` instead of throwing exceptions if there are io or access problems.

Comment: have tried httpcontext.current.server.mappath, that did not work.

Comment: have tried disabling anoynmous authentication that did not work